# Bootstrap 5 columns grid width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand this table in Bootstrap 5.

[image]

So far what I understand is this:

- Extra small (xs) - targeting mobile devices that have a max-width of
  576 pixels.
- Small (sm) – targeting devices with a resolution greater than 540
  pixels but smaller than 576 pixels.
- Medium (md) - targeting devices greater than 720 pixels and smaller
  than 768 pixels.
- Large (lg) - targeting devices that are larger than 960 pixels but
  smaller than 992px pixels.
- Extra large (xl) - targeting devices that are larger than 1200pixels
  but smaller than 1140 pixels.
- Extra extra large (xxl) - is for all resolutions greater than or
  equal to 1400 pixels.

Wondering if what I stated above are correct? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand wrong. The right way is:

- Extra small (xs) - targeting mobile devices that have a max-width of
  575 pixels.
- Small (sm) – targeting devices with a resolution greater than and equal to 576 pixels but smaller than 768 pixels.
- Medium (md) - targeting devices greater than and equal to 768 pixels and smaller than 992 pixels.
- Large (lg) - targeting devices that are larger than equal to 992 pixels but smaller than 1200px pixels.
- Extra large (xl) - targeting devices that are larger than equal to 1200 pixels but smaller than 1140 pixels.
- Extra extra large (xxl) - is for all resolutions greater than or equal to 1400 pixels.